# Does Gnome Boxes support stretching guess screen to fit the window?

Tags: virtualization, 4k-monitor, gnome-boxes

I tried to install Gnome Boxes on Ubuntu 22.04 (beta). The default one was Snap, but after downloading an OS image, it failed to start the guest. So, I uninstalled it and installed the package version instead. I downloaded the Ubuntu Server image and it started this time, but the guest screen (console) was a tiny small window on my 4K monitor. Resizing the window of Gnome Boxes did not make the guest screen bigger; the guest screen was the same size at the centre and only padding was added. It was almost impossible to use the guest like that.

I could not find any way to enlarge the guest screen. I searched the web and found some page mentioning some sort of guest-side add-on, but that will probably work when the guest is a GUI desktop and is installed. It won't work at the installer screen or a terminal window of Ubuntu Server.

VMware has Stretch mode, which can make the terminal guest screen fill the 4K host monitor. Gnome Boxes does not have a similar function?

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *testing* with *beta* freeze just *hit* & *beta* release on 31-March-2022

Comment: @guiverc I don't think this problem is specific to Ubuntu 22.04. Does Gnome Boxes have the ability to stretch the guest screen or not?

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Boxes does not seem to have a native way to controlling the guest resolution. You may need to explore a client/server set of libraries called SPICE. You will need to install SPICE on both your host and guests in order to get some functionality with a desktop environment (they even have an Android client). This will only work on systems with graphical UI that you can install a supported SPICE client.

If you are using Ubuntu Server or any non-graphical Linux/Unix systems, you are better off just using SSH to connect to your VM rather than using the graphical terminal. Just enable the SSH and basically get the IP address in the guest, and use any SSH client from your host to connect to VM.

With KVM + QEMU/libvirt there are all types of advanced CLI and API controls, but those are not exposed or implemented in Gnome Boxes. If you want easier, more user friendly desktop virtualization which allows for much more control via GUI, you may want to try VirtualBox instead.